# Odoo 13 Error compute_function on one2many field

Tags: python, odoo-13

I want to synchronize one part of my One2Many field in a different model with the right match in another model. I have an one2many field in project.project which includes a field emp_id(hr.employee) and role_id(project.roles). Now in the model account.analytic.line (2nd picture) there is already the right employee so I just want to compute the right role and display it in the right field. But as far as I am now I get singleton error, I know its cause of many objects and it expects ony one. But to be honest I dont know how to compute the correct role of the right project.

[This is my One2Many field (project.project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu2Ec.png)
There are many projects and i need to get the correct one with the exactly correct timesheet.
[Role field (last row) account.analytic.line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMpEq.png)

My compute function:

```
class RoleSync(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'
    #_inherits = {'project.project': 'list_id'}

    role_field_id = fields.Many2one(string='Role', compute='_compute_role')

    def _compute_role(self):
        emp = []
# to get the one2many field with the correct project
        list = self.env['project.project'].search(
            [('name', '=', self.project_id.name)]).list_id 
 # to get the right timesheet for the correct project
        timesheet = self.env['account.analytic.line'].search(
            [('project_id.name', '=', self.name)]) 
 # iterate through timesheet and get name of employee
        for val in timesheet:  
            emp.append(val.name)
 # nested loop for list with employee names and the one2many field
        for a in emp:          
            for b in list:
# if the names are the same
                if a.emp == b.emp_id.name:  
# take the role and display it in the field
                    self.role_field_id = b.emp_id.role_id
```

The Error:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 745, in get
    value = self._data[field][record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 18

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1004, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 751, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: ('account.analytic.line(18,).role_field_id', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5101, in ensure_one
    _id, = self._ids
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1285, in search_read
    return self.do_search_read(model, fields, offset, limit, domain, sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1304, in do_search_read
    return Model.web_search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 39, in web_search_read
    records = self.search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4951, in search_read
    result = records.read(fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 2965, in read
    vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5731, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 2333, in __get__
    return super().__get__(records, owner)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1028, in __get__
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 1113, in compute_value
    records._compute_field_value(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4003, in _compute_field_value
    getattr(self, field.compute)()
  File "/opt/Odoo/Custom_Addon/project_addon/models/analytic_class.py", line 18, in _compute_role
    [('project_id.name', '=', self.name)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 988, in __get__
    record.ensure_one()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5104, in ensure_one
    raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: account.analytic.line(18, 12, 9, 6)
```

Comment: `self` is a recordset, loop over self to get records one by one. You can check the examples given in the [developer](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#computed-fields) documentation

Comment: I want to ask can i use @api.depends('list_id') for getting the list_id from a different class and using it locally in the compute function?

Comment: Dependencies can be dotted paths when using sub-fields: `@api.depends('line_ids.value')`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have nearly reached my goals but there is always an _unknown variable with the role. [ See Picture ](https://ibb.co/kXcCzRk)

Comment: Define the `comodel_name` of the role field, which is mandatory for computed many2one fields.

Comment: I always get this kind of error : 
https://ibb.co/8dN5jtq
<br></br>
[My Computed Function](https://ibb.co/DCTFpJT)

Comment: Nvm, I used Char field instead of many2one now it is working , thanks a lot

Comment: Odoo expects an ID, and it got a string instead, probably  the record name (role name)